# Change Lable text from OpenCV ProcessImage method on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am processing video on iOS platform using OpenCV.

**Question:**

However I cant change the text on UILabel on UIViewcontroller with in ProcessImage method.

Is there a way to do this or call a function?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're running into an issue with trying to update UI components on a background thread.  Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Update UI here
});
```

To force a block of code to execute on the main UI thread.